# Picture is not visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The picture is not visible on my HTML page. Image Path values are true. I didn't get an error in the code part, but what is the problem?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Wrapper, Title} from './Header.styled';
const Header = ({children}) => {    
    
    return <Wrapper>
        <Title>KFC</Title>
        <div className='logoDiv'>
            <img src="../../assets/logo.png"/>
        </div>
        
        
    </Wrapper>;
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import your logo file first.

```
import logo from '../../assets/logo.png';
```

Then you need to call the image using the img tag.

```
<img className='logo' src={logo} />
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. My problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Import your `logo` and use it inside the image source.

```
import React from 'react';
import icon from '../../assets/logo.png';
import {Wrapper, Title} from './Header.styled'
const Header = ({children}) =>       
    <Wrapper>
        <Title>KFC</Title>
        <div className='logoDiv'>
            <img src={icon} alt="icon" />
        </div>
    </Wrapper>;


export default Header;
```